# What's the easiest/best way to load auto-minified CSS files as strings with webpack and/or rollup?

Tags: css, webpack, rollup

What's the best way/best loader/best tooling/whatever to import CSS files as strings with Webpack and/or rollup, like in

```js
import dropDownStyles from './dropDown.css'
```

or

```js
import dropDownStyles from './dropDown.css?type=string' // or someting similar
```

Scoping class names etc. is not important in my use case, but the CSS file should automatically be minified by webpack/rollup.
Using CSS modules is not an option.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try please:

```
npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

And usage:

```
import dropDownStyles from 'raw-loader!./dropDown.css'
```

Using inline-loaders will override the loaders rule in webpack configuration.

Comment: Thank a lot Raz ... but raw-loader will not minify the CSS, will it?

Comment: Ah just saw it was one of your requirements. Nope it won't, only MiniCssExtractPlugin minifies css AFAIK.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure you'll need to extend MiniCssExtractPlugin or copy some of its functionality into your own plugin to achieve your goal. It'll be interesting to see if someone comes up with an answer that suites your requirements without him writing a custom loader/plugin, pretty much sure there aren't out of the box tools to achieve this.

Comment: Nevertheless, Raz, you were a great help. Thanks. Maybe that minification is not a really, really hard requirement. I'll just use raw-loader as you have suggested and will only take care about that minify thing as soon as it is really absolutely necessary. Who knows, maybe in a year or two there is a out of the box tool to do so. But frankly I am wondering a bit why almost nobody seems to need this feature. If you are implementing custom elements (maybe without using a webcomponent library) with shadow DOM then something like this "include minified css as string"  seems quite helpful IMHO.